# Unit testing Symfony 5 Mailer: MessageLoggerListener not available

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-mailer

I want to test email delivery in Behat tests in Symfony 5. Apparently, there is a `MailerAssertionsTrait` in the PHPUnit package for Symfony which uses the `MessageLoggerListener` to check the sent emails. Following this tutorial https://swag.industries/test-emails-with-symfony/, I adapted that trait for my Behat context.

Unfortunately the service `mailer.message_logger_listener` does not seem to be available in the Symfony container. No matter if I set the `MAILER_DSN` to `null://null` or to an actually working transport.

I saw that this listener is being registered in the file `vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Resources/config/mailer_debug.php`, which leads me to believe that I have to enable debug mode for the `symfony/mailer` package in some way. But I did not yet find out how exactly that is done.

How do I enable the `MessageLoggerListener` for the `symfony/mailer` package in my test environment?

Comment: You can try to copy service definition from `vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Resources/config/mailer_debug.php` and add it to `config/services_test.yaml`.

Comment: @vstelmakh thanks for your reply. I didn't think of configuring the package in my own app config, but it makes sense. It didn't load the file at all at first until I figured out that as of Symfony 5.1, `*.php` config files are not loaded anymore by default, so I had to change my `Kernel.php` to load `*.php` config files too. The file is now definitely being loaded, but the `MessageLoggerListener` still can't be retrieved. Calling `$container->has('mailer.message_logger_listener')` still returns false.

Comment: I now found out that the `mailer.message_logger_listener` had already been registered correctly, but it is set to private, as any other service in the service container that is not explicitly set to being public, hence I could not fetch it from the container using `has()` and `get()`. I could inject it to my Behat test case using constructor injection. However, the logger seems to be meant to be used only with the `mailer.data_logger` because it does register the sent email, but when I try to get the recorded events, they have been reset...